# Laravel SSH connection

Tags: php, laravel-5, ssh

I have a question regarding a task that I want to accomplish. I have a website whose back-end is written in **laravel 5** and using **mysql** as a database. On the website dashboard there is tab named **status**. What I wanted to do is that when I click on the **status** tab it will fetch a server IP from the table that is already present in the database. Make ssh connection on that server IP, execute a bash command on the remote terminal and show the output of the command on the dashboard.
Is it possible to do in laravel?
I have seen 2 packages that are available in laravel for ssh connection. One is **ssh** by **laravelcollective** and other is **envoy** by **laravel** but i am unable to figure out how they will accomplish this task. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just a suggestion. If your production server allows that you use the `shell_exec(any command)` in the `kernel.php` file. You could do magic. Honestly,I do not comprehend the extent of your question. But if linux commands could help you out, this is my suggestion. You could even build laravel commands combining what you wish to achieve and run them as events or cron jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is by using the `ssh2_connect` which allows you to create the connection and then you can execute commands and retrieve the results in via callbacks

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php) you have the full documentation which comes with nice examples on everything I said before.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try your suggestion and let you know if it works.

Comment: I have used **phpseclib** library to accomplish the task.